# Request returns Array

Tags: php

Table:

```
id  |  date  |  number
----------------------
 1  | 01.01  |    12
 2  | 02.01  |    15
 3  | 03.01  |   174
 4  | 04.01  |    14
 5  | 05.01  |    65
 6  | 06.01  |    78
 7  | 07.01  |    69
 8  | 08.01  |   147
 9  | 09.01  |    12
 10 | 10.01  |    87
```

I'm trying to output last 7 values from `date` ordered by `id` with some implode.

```
$day=$mysqli->query("SELECT `date` FROM `online` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 7"); 
 $day=$day->fetch_all(); 
   $day="'". implode("', '", $day) . "'";
echo $day;
```

`echo` returns `'Array',` x7. How to output `'01.01','02.01', etc.`?

Comment: I am not sure but maybe when you call the output of the query you have to define the array? as $day[0]

Comment: fetch_all() will return a two-dimensionnal array, first level is the rows, the second level is the columns. Requesting only one column doesn't magically change each column to a string, it's still an array.

Comment: @EdgarCooper did you tried to look into documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)?

Comment: if you purely want to output them, just use `var_dump($day);` instead of `echo $day;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your code uses `$day` to store at least three different things during its lifetime. While the compiler doesn't complain, it is confusing and difficult to understand for humans. Let rewrite your code to use different variables for different items:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `date` FROM `online` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 7");
$days = $result->fetch_all();
$text = "'" . implode("', '", $days) . "'";
echo $text;
```

A quick `print_r($days)` will reveal you that the value returned by `$result->fetch_all();` is a two-dimensional array. Each of its items is an array, one row from the result set.

There are many ways to get the `date` column of each row returned by `$result->fetch_all()`. The way that is the easiest to read and understand is to ask [`mysqli_result::fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) to return the rows as [associative arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-all-parameters) indexed by column names (by default it returns arrays numerically indexed) then use the function [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get only the values of the `date` column and pass only them to [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

The code is like this:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `date` FROM `online` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 7");
$days = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$text = "'" . implode("', '", array_column($days, 'date')) . "'";
echo $text;
```

The next step towards **readability** (with a small performance penalty) and **correctness** is to quote each day individually *before* joining them into the final string. The function [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) can be used for that; it applies a callback function to each item of the passed array and returns a new array that contains the values returned by the callback function.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `date` FROM `online` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 7");
$days = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$text = implode(', ',                 // Join the quoted days with commas
    array_map(
        function($day) {
            return "'{$day}'";        // Put each day in single quotes
        },
        array_column($days, 'date')   // Get only the 'date' column
    )
);
echo $text;
```

A quick test with a query that doesn't return any result (use an empty table or add an impossible `WHERE` condition) reveals that this code doesn't produce any output (which is correct since there is no data retrieved from the database) while the original code produces an empty pair of apostrophes (`''`), which is not correct (let's remember the requirement was to put each day in single quotes and separate the days with comma and a space.)

Comment: 1 question more. I changed `desc` to `asc` to make my graph show well. It outputs from `01.01` to `07.01`, but if there will be `08.01` in table, it wouldn't be shown. If I will use `desc`, my graph inverts horisontally.

Comment: `LIMIT` applies after `ORDER BY`. Without `LIMIT` the query returns all the rows in the order specified by `ORDER BY`. `LIMIT n` keeps only the first `n` rows. If you want to get the last `n` rows from the resultset then you sort them descending then sort them again in the client code (PHP or javascript) in the desired order. Or wrap the original query into another `SELECT` that does the desired re-ordering: ``SELECT * FROM (SELECT `date` FROM `online` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 7) a ORDER BY `id` ASC``.

Comment: Now it returns an error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_all() on boolean (in fetch_all)
Stack trace:
#0 {main}

Comment: This means the query is not correct SQL. There is no `id` column in the resultset returned by the inner query. The correct query is ``SELECT `date` FROM (SELECT `id`, `date` FROM `online` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 7) a ORDER BY `id` ASC``.

Answer (score 0):

Each element in the fetched array is an array of its columns.

One way to unravel it with with an `array_map` call:

```
$first = function($arr) {
    return $arr[0];
};

$day = $day->fetch_all(); 
$day = array_map($first, $day);
$day = "'". implode("', '", $day) . "'";
echo $day;
```

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '$day' (T_VARIABLE)` - `$day = array_map($first, $day);`

Comment: @EdgarCooper forgot a semicolon there, thanks for noticing. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Without any additional `php` functions, just pure *MySql* approach:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT group_concat(`date` separator ', ') as dates
                        FROM `online` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 7");

$days = $result->fetch_assoc();    // $days['dates'] contains the needed string
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

Issue is $day->fetch_all() generate associative array and implode doesn't support associative arrays

Try:

```
$sql = "SELECT `date` FROM `online` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 3";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$day = [];

while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {

  $day[]=$row[0]; }


$day="'". implode("', '", $day) . "'"; echo $day;
```

Answer (score -1):

To see if what you have is what you want, begin to replace :

```
echo $day;
```

With :

```
print_r($day);
```

If you see what you want, it's that your SQL request works well. Next, navigate in arrays like @Mureinik says. 
If you want a cleaner display, you can use :

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($day);echo "</pre>";
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre "pre" element represents preformatted text. Whitespace inside this element is displayed as typed.

Comment: Nope, still returns `Array`